# Removing temperature from black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, temperature

Suppose I take the metric of a three dimensional AdS-Schwarzschild black brane (Note not actually a black hole!):

$ds^2 = \frac{L^2 dr^2}{r^2 W} + \frac{r^2}{L^2} \left[ - W dt^2 + dz^2 + dx^2 \right]$

with $W=1-\frac{r_H}{r}$, where $r=r_H$ is the horizon position (and can be shown to be equivalent to the temperature by Euclidean methods or direct computation of surface gravity).

My question is that if I make the rescaling $t=\frac{1}{r_H} T$, $z=\frac{1}{r_H} Z$, $x=\frac{1}{r_H} X$ and $r=r_H R$, then I arrive at the following metric:

$ds^2 = \frac{L^2 dR^2}{R^2 \tilde{W}} + \frac{R^2}{L^2} \left[ - \tilde{W} dT^2 + dZ^2 + dX^2 \right]$, where $\tilde{W} = 1 - \frac{1}{R^4}$.

Thus, the rescaling appears to have removed temperature from the black brane. Or have I just moved to units in which temperature is $r_H=1$? Is this just like when I move to coordinates where $c=1$? Although that's kind of different because $c$ is not a parameter in the same sense that temperature is?

What's going on?!?!

Thanks.

Comment: Temperature is not an absolute quality, so you should not expect it to be invariant under change of coordinates. What you have done is similar to the transformation from Celsius to Fahrenheit degrees - simply a change of perspective ;)

Comment: @Newbie 1, By absolute you mean diffeomorphism invariant? 2, Why would the first metric be preferred? Because it allows us to do thermodynamics? 3, I would say I can do thermodynamics with the second metric - doesn't this mean temperature is redundant?

Comment: @Newbie Normally if I can make a coordinate transformation to remove a parameter, I can conclude that that parameter is redundant and then rewrite the metric in new coordinates with n-1 parameters. Obviously I don't want that to happen with temperature - why am I not allowed to do this? Why is it different?

Comment: You are not obliged to prefer the first metric. By "not absolute" I mean that it is frame-dependent (just like entropy). This said, though, I should also point out that for a fixed observer temperature is an absolute quantity (its meaning doesn't change with time or distance) and so you can do thermodynamical analysis with it.

Comment: But you haven't removed the parameter temperature from your second metric? You just re-innovated the units, in which it's measured...